# How to connect Vsee to Firebase using Active API

Tags: php, curl, firebase

I am using VSee video calling plugin, but now I need to connect this plugin to firebase API.
So far I have implemented this code below:

Request

```
    https://api.vsee.com/activeapi/gettoken?apikey=<API KEY>
    { 
        "secretkey": SECRET KEY
    }
```

I receive below response.

```
    {
        "state_url": https://XXX.firebaseio.com/release/X,
        "token": token string
    }
```

Please help me, when someone has developed already.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for some of the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) as you're not really having an issue.